# Ember get current url in RESTadapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

using ember 1.13.2 with ember data 1.13.4 in conjunction with a rails backend.

trying to implement a HMAC authentication with ember and ember data (restadapter)

```
class AuthHelper
  authHeader: (adapter)->
    ...

Frontend.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend(
  headers: (-> 
    'Authorization': new AuthHelper().authHeader(@)
  ).property().volatile())
```

for this I need to get the url the request is going to be send to.

how can I get this url? or do I need to construct it manually by collecting host and pluralized models name? where to get the get params ?

**UPDATE**

I was able to accomplish it with the following code:

```
Ember.$.ajaxPrefilter (options, oriOpt, jqXHR) ->
  authHeader = AuthHelper.authHeader(options.url)
  jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authHeader)
  return
```

the complete solution can be found here: https://github.com/psunix/js-frameworks-api-auth

Maybe someone knows a more Ember way for doing this.

Comment: So you want the URL of the current page that the user is on?

Comment: no, the XHR request's url